# RadGrid Specify ComboBox skin on edit?

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

I have a grid and a skin specified for that and it works fine.  However, on the contained GridDropDownColumn columns, when it shifts to edit mode, the combo box is created nicely, but does NOT inherit the skin of the grid as the text boxes do.  This results is a mixture of font sizes in the edit row (inline edit).

How can I tell the created ComboBox which skin to use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I come upon similar glitch in one of my projects and what helped me to bypass it to set the EnableAjaxSkinRendering property of the RadComboBox editors to true on ItemCreated. Try that to see how it goes.

Dick